# Unity UI doesn't set the interactability to true in script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've had this problem before, and I can't stand it anymore. Why and how does this happen? I'm new to C# and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonActivate : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool Test;
    Button ButtonHere;
    void Update()
    {
        Test = true;
        if (Test == true)
        {
            ButtonHere.interactable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get error messages in the Console window? Most likely `ButtonHere` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible mistakes I can think of are:

- Buttonhere is `null` or is referencing the wrong GameObject.
- The script isn't attached to anything, try attaching it to something like the button itself or the 'Main Camera'.